# References in C# - What are examples of missing or mismatching references at runtime

Tags: c#, reference

I understand that there are basically two different kinds of dependencies in C#:
Those needed for compiling and those needed to run.
While it is pretty obvious that building/compiling fails when there are missing references,
it is not that clear to me how an application might still break at runtime because of missing or mismatching dependencies at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two possibilities.

## 1 Missing dependency at runtime

If you compile your application against a dependency (mostly an Assembly as a .dll file), but you do not have it on the machine / folder where your application runs, it will fail at runtime.

Example: You have a .dll in your source folder but forgot to copy it to the output filder.

## 2 Version incompatibility

If you compiled your application against a dependency with Version A and at runtime it uses Version B, it might fail if the methods you are calling are incompatible or missing. This will result in a `MissingMethodException`

Example: The method at compile time looks like this `Foo(string bar)`, but the method at runtime looks like this `Foo(string bar, string baz)`.

Comment: okay got point 1), already familiar with that problem :) but point 2) how can an app that is compiled with version x of a dependecy actually still use version y?

Comment: I might add that the second case needs to be considered for things like plugins, where you expect different versions of both the host and plugin to be somewhat compatible.